# Подключение jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/allscripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></script>
```

Где здесь может быть неправильно подключение

Comment: Только в путях может быть проблема. Или файл jquery.js пустой. лол

Comment: Исходя из вопроса ваши js файлы должны находиться в папке js - проверьте. Также что значит непрвильно подключено? Что не работает? Конкретнее вопрос необходимо ставить!
Может также быть проблема с версиями jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Все зависит от того, как у вас называется файл с jquery (назвать вы его могли как угодно) и куда вы его положили. Используйте cdn.

Всегда по возможности используйте библиотеки, которые хранятся в гугле, поскольку они уже закешированы у большинства пользователей и будут подгружаться быстрее.

Просто напишите:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```